# npx foo – "command not found: foo"

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

```
C:\Users\xehpuk>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.348]

C:\Users\xehpuk>node -v
v11.11.0

C:\Users\xehpuk>npm -v
5.3.0

C:\Users\xehpuk>npx -v
9.2.0

C:\Users\xehpuk>npx foo
command not found: foo
```

With the last command, the file `C:\Users\xehpuk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js` is opened in my default text editor. What's going on?

Comment: Presumably the `foo` command does not exist globally or locally? See related issue [#116](https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/116)

Comment: @RobC In my experience, `npx` just installs missing packages locally automatically if they are not already installed.  Maybe this has not always been the case?

Comment: Yes, that should be the expected result, i.e. `npx` downloads `foo` and executes it. Is the `foo` part in your question there to indicate any package, or is this only happening when trying to install the [`foo`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/foo) package ?

Comment: @RobC Nice find, seems to be exactly the same issue. `foo` stands for any package that's not installed, including the "real" `foo`.